# Trying to interrupt an interactive UICollectionView layout transition

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

### Is there a way to begin a new `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` in the middle of an existing interactive layout transition?**

#### Description [[sample project]](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5h0gvcn_L3zWTJ5b0I2VGlnbms)

We have built a UI component that represents different states with a set of `UICollectionViewLayout`s. Each of these layouts is attached to a pan gesture to navigate between the states. Once the pan gesture is finished, we call either `cancelInteractiveTransition()` or `finishInteractiveTransition()` to finish the transition.

All of this works as expected, but we cannot figure out how to interrupt an interactive transition. An example use case would be the user has swiped up to navigate to a new state, but then wants to swipe down to go back before the animation has finished.

#### Things we have tried:

- Immediately calling `startInteractiveTransition` when the next pan gesture begins, regardless of the previous state

  - This results in a crash on `setTransitionProgress:` since our other transition layout is still active (has not finished animating)
- Returning a custom `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` that had the ability to snapshot all `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` in the middle of a transition.

  1. We would snapshot the layout attributes whenever a new panGesture
     began
  2. We would then adjust the `transitionProgress` to `1.0` and call `finishInteractiveTransition` to finish the transition in it’s
     paused state
  3. We would initialize a new custom `UICollectionViewLayout` with our paused `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]` and try to
     transition from there to our new desired interactive final layout

     - This temporarily paused the animation, but since we have to call `cancelInteractiveTransition` or `finishInteractiveTransition` after our initial pan gesture is finished, there doesn’t seem to be a way to adjust the end layout.

---

*GIF showing control:*
[image: GIF showing control]